# If with variables not parameters in azure pipeline problem

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am putting following code in azure pipeline:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.enableAddonVM, true) }}:     
  - template: ../task-templates/addonVM.yml
    parameters:
      serviceConnectionName: ${{ variables.serviceConnectionName }}
      customerResourceGroup: $(resourceGroupName)
      location: ${{ variables.location }}
```

Following are my observations:

1. The template get skipped. I checked the value by printing it in task before it. It is showing true. Still it gets skipped.
2. I also applied **condition** next to **template** as shown below

   - template: ../task-templates/addonVM.yml

     condition:
     But still it get failed. We were not able to use **condition** after template.
3. I also checked addonVM.yml after removing condition. addonVM.yml was working propely.

So, My final question is how can insert variables within if condition? Is there some way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: try with `${{ if eq(variables['enableAddonVM'], true) }}:`

Comment: This is a compile time construct. If the value of the variable isn't available when the template is parsed, the value can't be used. In those cases you'll need to rely on `condition: $[[ ... ]]` which will be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If with variables not parameters in azure pipeline problem

It depends on whether the variable `enableAddonVM` already existed before compilation.

Just as jessehouwing pointed that the template variables `${{ variables.var }}` are processed at **compile time**:

Check the document [Template expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax) for some more details.

So, if the variable `enableAddonVM` is generated at previous task, it could not be grabbed at compile time. That is because this variable is generated at runtime.

To resolve this issue, you could use `condition`, like:

```
  steps: 
    - template: ../task-templates/addonVM.yml
      parameters:
        serviceConnectionName: ${{ variables.serviceConnectionName }}
        customerResourceGroup: $(resourceGroupName)
        location: ${{ variables.location }} 
  condition: eq(variables.enableAddonVM, true)
```

Comment: Resolved the issue. Thank you